# I am not receiving any message from the websocket, rxjs and .net

Tags: .net, angular, websocket, rxjs, azure-web-pubsub

I am trying to do a very simple websocket solution where, from a dotnet application, I send an integer to the socket and then from my rxjs I want to get that value.

Sending is very easy and I don't get any errors. So I guess the values are being sent (I use the Webpubsub in azure where I've created a client url from there):

[image: Console app to send value to socket]

But, receiving is not working at all. Nothing is happening. This copied directly from RxJS website:

[image: rxjs code]

The code inside that onInit is triggering first time the page loads but then nothing more.

In the browser, it looks like the hub is connected (in devtools I see that the hub is in pending mode which should be correct):

[image: devtools]

Comment: Hi @dddd9999, provide the code in a text format rather than posting as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But, receiving is not working at all. Nothing is happening. This copied directly from RxJS website

- Create a service (e.g.,  `WebsocketService`) to manage the WebSocket connection. This service will handle connecting, sending, and receiving messages.

***websocket.service.ts :***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { webSocket, WebSocketSubject } from 'rxjs/webSocket';

const WS_ENDPOINT = 'wss://your-webpubsub-url'; // Replace with your actual Web PubSub URL

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class WebsocketService {
  private ws: WebSocketSubject<any>;

  constructor() {}

  public connect(): void {
    this.create();
  }

  private create() {
    if (this.ws) {
      this.ws.unsubscribe();
    }

    this.ws = webSocket<any>(WS_ENDPOINT);
    this.ws.subscribe(); // Start listening for messages
  }

  public close() {
    if (this.ws) {
      this.ws.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  public sendMessage(message: any) {
    this.ws.next(message);
  }
}
```

- Inject the  `WebsocketService`  into the Angular components where you want to use WebSocket communication.
- Subscribe to the  `messages$`  observable to receive WebSocket messages. Handle incoming messages as needed.

***app.component.ts :***

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { WebsocketService } from '../websocket.service'; // Adjust the path

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private messagesSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private websocketService: WebsocketService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.websocketService.connect();

    this.messagesSubscription = this.websocketService.messages$.subscribe({
      next: (message: any) => {
        console.log('Received message:', message);
        // Handle the message as needed
      },
      error: (error: Error) => {
        console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
      },
      complete: () => {
        console.log('WebSocket connection closed');
      },
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.messagesSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.websocketService.close();
  }
}
```

- Unsubscribe from the WebSocket subscription when the component is destroyed (in  `ngOnDestroy`).

**Connection status :**

[image]

**Receive messages :**
[image]